# How to properly emulate `eval_gemfile` for `gem install -g`?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

When using `eval_gemfile` in `Gemfile` Bundler works. But `gem install -g` fails with

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `eval_gemfile' for #<Gem::RequestSet::GemDependencyAPI:0x000000000268a388>
```

Using `eval File.read(...)` works but I'm worried about any implications that I need to watch for.

Comment: What is the gem giving the error? What version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: @WildWilyWilly , any Gemfile with `eval_gemfile` . Ruby 2.7

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the only reason to use `eval_gemfile` is readability and nicer syntax error reporting:

https://github.com/rubygems/bundler/commit/c6100f6bd246a8259f159285967f075b592e80c9

wrt the `#untaint` call, it appears to be some remains of 1.8.7 test suite requirements. I tested it working without `#untaint` on 2.5.5 so I wouldn't bother to add this call:

https://github.com/rubygems/bundler/pull/4770#discussion-diff-71091844